# I need to find what users where logged on to the network (AD) at a given date and time

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to trace who logged into a server at a given time but the event logs have been deleted for time period I need.
Can I get a list of all users logged in to the domain at a specific time?

Comment: Pretty unlikely, but you might get some results from searching the security event logs on the domain controllers for user accounts doing things, maybe searching the event logs of every workstation for who was logged on, and the webserver logs for any internal websites to look for usernames in the access logs. It won't be quick or thorough, but it might give some indication.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no. (You only see failure logon by default) You need to activate Success Audit in your default domain policy. Which in turn make a lot of log.

> •In the DC go to Group Policy Management Editor > Default Domain
>   Policy > Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings >
>   Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy
>
> •Set the Audit
>   account logon events, directory services access, logon events to
>   "Success, Failure".